# Redis cache updating

Tags: caching, redis

EDIT2: Clarification: The code ALREADY has refresh cache on miss logic. What I'm trying to do is reducing the number of missed cache hits.

I'm using Redis as a cache for an API. The idea is that when the API receives a call it first checks the cache and if the data isn't in cache the API will fetch it and cache it afterwards for next time.

At the moment the configuration is the following:

```
maxmemory 50mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

That is, use at most 50mb memory, keep trying keys in there and when memory is full start by deleting the least recently used keys (lru).

Now I want to introduce a second category of keys. For this second category I'm going to set a certain expiry time. Now I would like to set up a mechanism such that when these keys expiry this mechanism kicks in and refreshes them (and sets new expiry).

How do I do this?

EDIT:
Some progress. It turns out that Redis has a pub/sub messaging system which in particular can dispatch messages on event. One of them is expiring keys, which can be enabled as such:

```
notify-keyspace-events Ex
```

I found this code can describes a blocking [python process subscribing to Redis' messaging system](https://gist.github.com/jobliz/2596594). It can easily be changed to detect keys expiring and make a call to the API when a key expires, and the API will then refresh the key.

```
def work(self, item):
    requests.get('http://apiurl/?q={param}'.format(param=item['data']))
```

So this does precisely what I was asking about.

Often, this feels way too dangerous and out of control. I can imagine a bunch of different situations under which this will very quickly fail.

So, what's a better solution?

Comment: Keyspace notifications, like Redis PubSub, aren't guaranteed to be delivered - for example, if your worker is disconnected, you'll be missing the messages. I still recommend that you include the refresh-catch-on-miss logic in your code.

Comment: Like I said elsewhere, my code already have refresh-catche-on-miss logic, and what I'm trying to do it avoiding misses. Also, it's a cache: if the notification is lost, oh well, we won't refresh that key and it will be refreshed when it's missed. But hopefully we can avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

http://redis.io/topics/notifications

> Keyspace notifications allows clients to subscribe to Pub/Sub channels
>   in order to receive events affecting the Redis data set in some way.
>   Examples of the events that is possible to receive are the following:
>
> All the keys expiring in the database 0. (e.g)

...

> EXPIRE generates an expire event when an expire is set to the key, or
>   a expired event every time setting an expire results into the key
>   being deleted (see EXPIRE documentation for more info).

Comment: I just edited my question to include what you just said (please check). Feels a bit out of control though.

Comment: Because it's synchronous ?

Comment: Couple of problems off the top of my head. A) if TTL is the same for every key, and the number of key times the time it takes to make a call for key key is longer than TTL, this process will never finish and in fact a queue will just build up. B) what if too many keys happen to expire simultaneously? Again queue build up.

Comment: Expire has constant time (i.e. O(1)) execution. It means that if you expire a LOT of keys, it will always execute below a time threshold. So A) won't occur. And I didn't get why B) is an issue! :)

Comment: I know what constant time means, and it's irrelevant for what I pointed out: if keys live 1 hour and it takes me 2 hours to put all of them in memory, you don't see a problem? It's a big problem which exists regardless of expire execution time.

Comment: What is the kind of structure you intend to control with this ? I had a 1 million members sorted set that took 5min to `ZADD` in one application, and that's the largest wait time I ever faced on a data insertion.

Comment: It's stuff generated by calls to external APIs. Each one of them takes a while.

Comment: You can't precise the key type ? Each kind of data structure have different insertion times. SET is constant.

Comment: Key type is string (a 100 char or so string) but again, this has nothing to do with insertion or expiry. It has to do with actually generating the data, which has to be pulled from the network. My question isn't one about redis' data structures, but about software architecture.

Answer (score -1):

To expire keys, just use Redis' built-in expiry mechanism. You don't need to refresh the cache contents on expiry, the simplest is to do it when the code experiences a cache miss.

Comment: That doesn't solve my issue, as missing cache hits is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You'll always have cache misses, unless your cache is big enough to hold the entire db.